# "report a concern" link on my iphone application review page?

Tags: iphone, comments, app-store, review

Someone did bad comments on my application on app store.and that really i hated.I know they are my competitors.

Is there any way to get user's email address or rather i can send them email directly?

I am confused ,for what purpose "report a concern" link is for?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: So how do you know they're your competitors and not just a user who had problems with the app? Even the best apps out there get negative reviews - you likely need to grow a thicker skin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'Report a concern' link IMHO might be there for you to highlight any offensive language being used in the review or something. If Apple was to give out every email address linked to a bad review, then there'd be an ongoing war among the application developers and the application users.

Answer (score 3):

No, you can't get such details or have a message sent. It's all fairly anonymous, and for good reason. Data protection laws exist for a reason!

Answer (score 3):

your competitors (plural) care enough about your app to write false reviews? Congratulation, this means your are quite successful with what you are doing.
So you should have at least ten comments in the range between "so lala" and "awesome" for each comment of your competitors.

If this is not the case I would reread the comments instead of accusing competitors.
Maybe whatever the comments say is true.

The best way to deal with bad comments is to check if you can remove the reason for the comment. And if they don't mention a reason (aka "the app is crap") then you should ignore them.
Everybody gets those comments. And even worse (at least for me) are comments from users who are to lazy or stupid to read the description. *"I don't know what the app does, so I give it one star"*.

I would love if a competitor would give my app a bad review. But they don't care who I am or what I do. :'-(